# Extreme downvoting after changing best answer

Tags: support, stack-overflow, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

On the 7th of May, I changed the accepted answer of a question on Stackoverflow.

The following day this happened:

```
May 7
-2 15:58 *unaccept* Stacking divs with variable height in 2 columns like Facebook Timeline
-2 18:53 *downvote* How to use Zend_Loader_Autoloader

May 8
-2 06:50 *downvote* Calculating at binary level in javascript
-2 21:32 *downvote* How to hide, encrypt and password protect a volume on my smartphone?
-2 21:32 *downvote* if(x==y==z) works, if(x!=y!=z) does not

May 9
-2 19:08 *downvote* Custom router using database items
-2 19:08 *downvote* mySQL select query based on lat / long data from zipcode
-2 19:08 *downvote* Does Zend have something like {strip} in Smarty?
-2 07:11 *downvote* Are there any free/open source databases which can properly store  arrays?
-2 07:11 *downvote* 'Talking' and 'learning' webapplications?
```

Does anyone has any idea what's going on? And can you please check if all downvotes came from the same person? Thanks

Comment: Nobody on Meta can really help you with this. It's best to get in touch with the mods directly by flagging one of your posts and explaining the situation in the reason field.

Comment: Thanks, I flagged it with a link to this topic so please do not remove this.

Comment: Mods can see this even if it gets closed and deleted before they see the flag (which looks to be unlikely at this point)

Comment: @awoodland Yup; I voted to close as dupe, but it'll still be visible to mods if needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A warning has been issued to the person who downvoted your posts.  Flagging a post of yours that was downvoted or bringing it up here on Meta is the right course of action when you suspect that you've been the victim of revenge downvoting.  You yourself should also refrain from engaging in malicious or revenge voting in the future.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, you're not the only "victim" - the [user you unaccepted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681807/my-head-hurts?tab=reputation) his answer got also attacked in the same time:

[image: screenshot]

This most likely means same person with three sockpuppet accounts, the system should catch this at some point and "refund" the lost reputation. Give it a week (2 days left) before becoming worried. :)